# Is there any difference between return and raise an Exception?

Tags: python, exception

Consider the following code:

```
def f(x):
    if x < 10:
        return Exception("error")
    else:
        raise Exception("error2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        f(5)                        # f(20)
    except Exception:
        print str(Exception)
```

Is there any difference?
When should I use `return Exception` and when should I use `raise`?

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`raise` and `return` are two inherently different keywords.

---

`raise`, commonly known as `throw` in other languages, produces an error in the current level of the call-stack. You can catch a raised error by covering the area where the error might be raised in a `try` and handling that error in an `except`.

```
try:
    if something_bad:
        raise generate_exception()
except CertainException, e:
    do_something_to_handle_exception(e)
```

`return` on the other hand, returns a value to where the function was called from, so returning an exception usually is not the functionality you are looking for in a situation like this, since the exception itself is not the thing triggering the `except` it is instead the `raise`ing of the exception that triggers it.